# How do you return the result in my code?

Tags: python, python-2.7, syntax, return

```
#Soccer Matchup Possibilities 
def soccermatchups(team1,team2):
    result=" "
    if (team1== "Brazil" and team2== "Canada"):
        result= "These teams could play each other in the World Cup!"
    if (team1== " England" and team2== "Netherlands"):
        result= "These teams could play each other in both Cups!"
        return(result)
```

I'm having this problem where the result shown above isn't being returned what do I do? I have been having some trouble with this! I would appreciate the help, this is in Python 2.7.

Comment: The `return` statement is indented one level too far to always return `result`

Answer (score 1):

If your second `if` evaluates to `False` the value returned is `None` since you only return a value *within* the second `if`.

Move the `return result` (un-indent once) outside the second `if` statement to get a result regardless of what your `if` statements evaluate to:

```
def soccermatchups(team1, team2):
    result=" "
    if (team1== "Brazil" and team2== "Canada"):
        result= "These teams could play each other in the World Cup!"
    if (team1== " England" and team2== "Netherlands"):
        result= "These teams could play each other in both Cups!"

    # return value either way
    return(result)
```

Comment: It still doesn't return the result do I need to print something?

Comment: Does it maybe return an empty string `" "`? If so, none of your `if` clauses evaluated to `True`.

Comment: So inside I that I should put these teams could play each other?

Comment: Not exactly sure what you mean. What is the function returning?

Comment: Its returning nothing after I input those two teams, it only outputs/ returns <function soccermatchups at 0x000000000293D908> when I print(str(soccermatchups))

Comment: Well supply arguments for `soccermatch` and then call it, `print(soccermatchups("Brazil", "Canada")`.

Comment: Now it states none for some reason.

Comment: How exactly are you running this?

Comment: What do you mean? Like the python version?

Comment: The command you are using to call the function. When I run `print soccermatchups("Brazil", "Canada")` the result is `"These teams could play each other in the World Cup!"`.

Comment: I would put that under the result statement or should that go to a main program with a comment of output and then the print statement?

Comment: I just needed the print statement soccermatchups (team1,team2) on the main program part! Thanks for the help!

Answer (score 0):

Shift your last line one tab left.

If neither if statement evaluates to True you'll return None.

Comment: How could I display the result would I need a print statement?

Comment: print soccermatchups(team1, team2)

Comment: You should also set 'result' to something meaningful if you're going to go that route. Like result = False.

Comment: Yes I just needed that print statement I think this works now! Thanks a ton!

Answer (score 0):

```
def soccermatchups(team1,team2):
    if (team1== "Brazil" and team2== "Canada"):
        print "These teams could play each other in the World Cup!"
    if (team1== "England" and team2== "Netherlands"):
        print "These teams could play each other in both Cups!"
    return False


soccermatchups('Brazil', 'Canada')
soccermatchups('England', 'Netherlands')
```

Answer (score 0):

```
'''
#Soccer Match-ups Program
#Author: Coleton Ishmael
#Class: ICS3U
#Date: 11/10/15
'''
#Soccer Matchup Possibilities 
def soccermatchups(team1,team2):
    result="They cannot play each other in either the Euro or World Cup."
    if (team1== " Brazil" and team2== " Canada"):
        result= "They can play in the World Cup!"
    if (team1== " England" and team2== " Netherlands"):
        result= "They can play in both the Euro and World Cup!"
    return (result)

'''
Main Program
@parm Brian
@parm Alyssa
@return result
'''
# Get User's team selection
team1= raw_input (" Enter your first team:")
team2= raw_input (" Enter your second team:")


#Output
print soccermatchups(team1,team2)
```

This works like a charm! Thanks for the contributors, you guys helped me understand the concept! :)